# How to fix script so that I could copy unique range to another tab and avoid copying header of column?

Tags: google-apps-script

thank you ahead for your time and efforts.

Could you help me fix this script so that I can copy range from 'source' tab to 'target'tab as opposed to just a column? Currently it is copying only the column and column header. The 'source' tab will have data constantly refreshed from sql add-in and wish to only add new unique data to the bottom of 'target' tab (based on id in column A) while ignoring duplicate IDs in column A.

```
function keepUnique(){
  var col = 0 ; // choose the column you want to use as data source (0 indexed, it works at array level)

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  var ms = ss.getSheetByName("source");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("target");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data=ms.getDataRange().getValues();// get all data
  Logger.log(data);
  var newdata = new Array();
  for(nn in data){
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newdata){
      if(data[nn][col] == newdata[j][0]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newdata.push([data[nn][col]]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(newdata);
 sh.getRange(3,1,newdata.length,newdata[0].length).setValues(newdata);// paste new values sorted in column of your choice (here column 8, indexed from 1, we are on a sheet))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` to filter out unique values and `splice` to only return starting from the 2nd row of the data (excluding the header).

```
function keepUnique(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var ms = ss.getSheetByName("source");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("target");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ms.getDataRange().getValues();

  var newdata = data.reduce((a, c) => {
    // if column a is unique, include in the data
    if (!a.find(v => v[0] === c[0])) {
      a.push(c);
    }
    return a;
  // remove header
  }, []).splice(1);
  // write data starting from A3
  sh.getRange(3, 1, newdata.length, newdata[0].length).setValues(newdata);
}
```

#### Source:

[image: source]

#### Target:

[image: target]